# What happened with my bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I assigned a 50 points bounty to [a question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5471/reviving-li-ion-battery-in-freezer). I did not award the bounty, and neither was it auto-awarded. Still, I did lose the 50 points. Where did the bounty go?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, bounties are non-refundable, and are deducted when they are started, so they are not reassigned back to the user.  There were no answers with +2 or greater votes on the question, so it was not auto-awarded.

Please see: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

> A bounty is a special reputation award given to answers. It is funded by the personal reputation of the user who offers it, and is non-refundable.
>
> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

Comment: I read what you quoted, but didn't pay attention to the phrase *"is non-refundable"*, and so I thought that *"bounty is not awarded to anyone"* means that the bounty gets reassigned back to me. It's a pity, especially since I considered increasing the bounty to 100 once it expired. Now with 73 points this is not possible.

Comment: @feklee It's set up this way so that people can't offer bounties and then revoke them with no penalty.  That may not be as fair to the well-intentioned bounty starter like yourself, but I'm sure you understand it is necessary.

Comment: I understand. What I don't understand is why it is not possible to increase a bounty (or is it?).

Comment: You can start a higher bounty on the same question once the first one runs out.

Comment: @feklee Look at the bounty as payment for putting up an advertisement :) You don't get a refund if the ad doesn't work.