# Why was my bounty not auto-awarded?

Tags: support, bounty

Regarding the bounty I placed on: [Sodium Bisulfate vs Sodium Bisulfite](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/17321/sodium-bisulfate-vs-sodium-bisulfite).

At first glance this question looks like a dupe of this one: [What happened with my bounty?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/what-happened-with-my-bounty) but it's not, because my question had at least one answer with a score of over 2. I didn't get the information that I was hoping for, but Abel Friedman provided a good answer as far as it went. I didn't manually award the bounty because I never did get the answer I was looking for when I started the bounty, but I was fine with the idea that Abel was going to get half of it.

But now I come back, and it's as if the bounty never happened (except that my rep is reduced accordingly). What happened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in the answer to the other Meta question that you linked, auto-awarding requires that the answer with the two upvotes be added *after* the bounty was started.

All 3 answers were given on October 11th, and the bounty wasn't started until October 13th.

Unfortunately, there's nothing that can be done with it at this point, as the system doesn't allow bounties to be refunded.

Comment: I see - I missed the "after" line. I wouldn't ask for or expect a refund, I just wanted to be sure everything was working right.

Comment: Not a problem.  Thanks for checking about it.  There are some quirks in the rules to prevent "gaming" of the system, but sometimes those end up affecting well-intentioned users as a side effect.

Comment: @Jolenealaska And of course it's not to say that people can't *upvote* good answers after a bounty is started. While it's not a bounty, it's still nice. :-)